# How can I recover files from disk after git reset --hard

Tags: git, recovery

I reset to HEAD but did not stage the changes to the files I was working on.

Can I recover the changes made to the files using disk recovery? Or does git overwrite the files and save to the same location on the disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I recover the changes made to the LaTeX files using disk recovery?

That seems your best option (unless you are using an [IDE which saves a local history](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm))

An unstaged change is really never seen by git and cannot be recovered in the git repo.